# resource interpreted as document but transferred with mime type application/octet-stream pdf

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, nginx, download, mime-types

Don't know why I'm facing this issue not able to download pdf files in chrome browser, it is showing below error in Nginx server.

resource interpreted as document but transferred with mime type application/octet-stream pdf

Though I have included mime type as   application/pdf

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a warning then simply ignore it! It's just Chrome.

If not, try to include MIME Type as `application/octet-stream`.

Answer (score 0):

try to use those examples in your code.

[PDFobject](https://pdfobject.com/static.html)

this is a classic one:
if you can load localhost:8080/xyz123/PdfFile.pdf
then write like this:

```
<iframe src="./xyz123/PdfFile.pdf"  title="title">
   <a href="./xyz123/PdfFile.pdf"> ... </a>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue came up for me only for `.pdf` files. I changed the Application Pool's idenity to `Network Service` and it fixed the issue.

I am not sure why it worked as the response header still had the same `Content-Type`, but it worked.