# How do to make a file download with no MIME definition?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, mime

I have an XDFL form that the user needs to download, fill out and mail back. I tried this: [How to trigger a file download when clicking an html button or javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620698/how-to-trigger-a-file-download-when-clicking-an-html-button-or-javascript), but IIS threw back a **404.3 error**, saying that I need to add a MIME map.

I have to go through a bunch of red tape to get anything done to IIS (to add a MIME type). Is there an easier way to do this? Is there a way to say, "Treat this like a PDF and download it"?

It must be an XDFL file in order to have a digital signature.

```
<form method="get" action="Form.XFDL">
  <button class="button-to-link">Form</button>
</form>
```

Also, I'm using MVC.NET 4 with C#, if there's a way to accomplish this with that...

Comment: Could you provide server-side code?

Comment: AFAIK you can't make unknown (i.e. with no MIME-type) extensions download...