# Angular trigger a download on api response with filename

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am using angular and laravel. on a post request PHP creates a file and responds with the filename. How to use that filename and trigger download from angular.

api request

```
    var promise = $http.post('api/admin/ecs/singleecs', data).
        success(function (response) {
             //trigger file download
    })
```

php

```
PDF::loadHTML($html)->setPaper('a4')->setWarnings(false)->save('public/temp/'.$filename.'.pdf');
return $filename;
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue I would take the following steps:

1. Create a hidden a element on the page.

   ```
   <a id="fileDownloadLink" ng-hide="true" ng-href={downloadUrl} />
   ```
2. Use the following code to set the download URL and trigger the download.

   ```
   $scope.downloadUrl = response.data.fileName;

   var fileDownloadLink = document.getElementById("fileDownloadLink");
   fileDownloadLink.target = "_blank"; // Opens the file in a new window.
   fileDownloadLink.click();
   ```

Comment: your code was helpful, i needed to modify it. now i got the url `/home/abel/pro/public/sample.zip` but if i click it goes to `http://localhost:8000/home/abel/pro/public/sample.zip` how to remove localhost:8000 its been served for laravel php

Comment: Can you tell me what your response object is returning?

Comment: I am returning the path of the file created

Comment: Won't this be blocked by most browsers as a popup?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$window.location` to trigger the download. This will work only if "Content-Disposition: attachment" is in the response header of the `resource_url`:

```
var promise = $http.post('api/admin/ecs/singleecs', data)
                   .then(function (response) {
                     $window.location = response.resource_url;
                   });
```

**Note**: This is the angular version of the jQuery pattern illustrated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11620720/271178