# How to give browser "save image as" option to button

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I'm working on a canvas drawing project. I convert the canvas as an image, then I save that image as '.png'. I have to right click on the image and select the 'save image as' option. But I want to provide that option through a button. When I click the button it should be saved.

Any example or idea would be appreciated.

This is a js function that converts canvas to png.

```
 function save2()
 {
   window.open(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
   var gh=(canvas.toDataURL('png'));
   alert("converted");
 }
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620698/how-to-trigger-a-file-download-when-clicking-an-html-button-or-javascript) out. Just add the button with JS.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In modern browser you can use the download attribute

```
function save2() {
    window.open(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
    var gh = canvas.toDataURL('png');

    var a  = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = gh;
    a.download = 'image.png';

    a.click()
}
```

just trigger the function from a button, or insert the anchor in the page and style it as a button.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rhurdtqx/)

Comment: Thank you. It worked.How to change the download location?By default it's download to the Downloads folder in (C:) partition.

Comment: Not sure you can, you can only specify the filename, not the location, that's up to the user

Comment: This doesn't work on Safari (tested it on 9). In my case this opens 2 tabs, the browser hangs for a couple of seconds and no download is fired. It work on Chrome (49)

Answer (score 6):

First create a button for it 
 
    `<a href="#" class="button" id="btn-download" download="my-file-name.png">Download</a>`

Then add the following in javascript

```
var button = document.getElementById('btn-download');
button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    button.href = dataURL;
});
```

I have made an example for you 
[Check this out!](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wadevN)