# C# winforms, download image or copy to clipboard - can't use web requests

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, cefsharp

trying to get an image from my page, I had previously solved this by casting my WebBrowser.Document.DomDocument to an IHTMLDocument2, then copying it to clipboard, however I can no longer use this solution as I am using cefsharp browser. If I can convert the HTML page string back to WebBrowser I could hack it that way, [How to give browser "save image as" option to button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694433/how-to-give-browser-save-image-as-option-to-button). No luck. No error message to report. This means javascript could be used to get it. Either saving locally or copying to clipboard would be great. I can't use web requests. I don't think I can get it with HtmlAgilityPack but I've been trying that also. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: why can't you use web requests? you said you can download the whole page, why can't you download the image by itself?

Comment: 403 forbidden error

Comment: Do you get 403 forbidden because you are already authenticated? Because you can transfer your cookies to your web request. (had the same problem)