# Invoke download of a tag in html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I have an `<a>` tag which has already declared download attribute, like this:

```
<a href="123.png" download >Download it!</a>
```

Which the tag above, I can download the image from an url when clicking on the link. Now I have a button on my page, like this :

```
<button>Download by using button!</button>
```

Is there any way to let the user download not by clicking on the link but by clicking on the button instead.

My purpose is just for making an auto code that can download all the image with a specified class on a html page.

Comment: This answer may be helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620698/how-to-trigger-a-file-download-when-clicking-an-html-button-or-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
var el = document.{get you <a> tag by one of methods};
el.dispatchEvent(window.CustomEvent?new CustomEvent('click'):document.createEvent('click'));
```

This code may dont worked, but anyway you can use `createEvent` and `dispathEvent` to your tag to fire download action

UP:
In jQuery it more simple - `$('your a tag').trigger('click')` but jQuery may mess up in this things, native code will be more robust

Answer (score 0):

Using native javascript would be something like this:

HTML:

```
<a id="download-link" href="123.png" download >Download it!</a>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("download-link").click();
```

Comment: You should mark one of the answers as solved. And I'm glad to help.