# How to download file using input button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'd like to download JavaScript file when pushing download button. 
I understood HTML5 download attribute below.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18678698/5062103

But I'd like to download JS file when pushing input button because I don't want to use `<a>` tag. If using `<a>` tag, I have to upload file at first.

Is there any good idea? I'm wating for your good advice.

Comment: what "tag" you don't want to use? question is unclear

Comment: Actually you can use a little trick...create an href with the download attribute and hide it....then create your button, and add a listener to the click event, and inside the event trigger a click on the hidden href!

Comment: You have the answer as comment in the link you gave: `<button type="submit" onclick="window.open('file.doc')">Download!</button>`   here:http://stackoverflow.com/a/18676770/2022457

Comment: I solved this problem using <a> tag.  Still I'm thinking this is the simplest way.