# download a remote json with javascript as a file

Tags: javascript, json, download

I don't need to constuct a json then download, I already have the url of the json, I just need to download as a file. I've been followinw some answers of other threads but I can't get it. Some answers use externals libraries, jquery, etc. Is there a clean solution via javascript?

```
window.location.href = "my_url";
```

won't do the trick. I can't manage to download the file... only it shows throught the browser. For example, I tried this:  [How to trigger a file download when clicking an html button or javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620698/how-to-trigger-a-file-download-when-clicking-an-html-button-or-javascript?rq=1)

```
<form method="get" action="file.doc">
<button type="submit">Download!</button>
</form>
```

But don't know how to force the download with a json type file

Comment: "another domain"? You'd need a cross-domain request, which requires that the target site allows that. you could try something silly like `<script src="http://otherdomain.com/foo.json"></script>` and then extract the .text() of the script node. but then the other site might not like you scraping their stuff, and send over a nasty script instead, which your browser will then happily execute.

Comment: No, my own domain

Comment: I got it with this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620698/how-to-trigger-a-file-download-when-clicking-an-html-button-or-javascript?rq=1 <a href="path_to_file" download="proposed_file_name">Download</a> So simple.

Comment: Hmm, but it is not supported by Safari and IE11