# Best way to give a filename when clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to implement a function which allows to save a file of data previously computed by a JavaScript code.

HTML snippet code:

```
<button id="btn-save" type="submit" >Save to file</button>
```

JavaScript snippet code:

```
$("#btn-save").click( function() {

  for (var i=0; i< indexArray; i+=1)
  {
   content += arrayLatitude[i]+" "+arrayLongitude[i];
   content += "\n";
  }

  // Build a data URI
  uri = "data:application/octet-stream," + encodeURIComponent(content);
  location.href=uri;
});
```

The problem is that I have seen a lot of solutions involving the creation of "`a`" tag by doing :

```
title = document.title+"_"+day+".html",
a = document.createElement("a");
a.setAttribute("href", uri);
a.setAttribute("download", title);
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

But I don't know how to adapt it for "`button`" tag and not "`a`" tag.

What is the best way to accomplish directly this functionality with "`button`" tag ?

Comment: The `download` attribute only works on `<a>` elements. As a workaround you could use CSS to style your `a` to look like a `button`

Comment: Here are [some good ideas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620698/how-to-trigger-a-file-download-when-clicking-an-html-button-or-javascript).

Comment: thanks for these ideas, it helps me a lot