# jQuery Download file via hyperlink URI — Prevent Safari Redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, download

I'm using the javascript/jquery trick where you convert your string to a data URI, set the href of a link to it, then trigger the link click to initiate a direct download of the string as a file.

This works fine in Chrome, but in Safari, it redirects the page to a non-html page that contains the downloaded content. Is it possible to prevent this behaviour and have it act like it does in Chrome (direct file download)?

Comment: Did you try this one solution?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620698/how-to-trigger-a-file-download-when-clicking-an-html-button-or-javascript

Comment: If you'll provide good formated code example it will be much easy to help you.