# trigger click when i click neibour element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I want to download when `input` type submit is clicked.
Here is my code

```
<input type="submit" value="Try a sample" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit">

<a href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/pdf/AttackonNantucket.pdf" class="ddownload-button" download>Ram</a>
```

Comment: Possible [duplicate of 11620698](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620698/how-to-trigger-a-file-download-when-clicking-an-html-button-or-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger a file download when clicking an html button or javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620698/how-to-trigger-a-file-download-when-clicking-an-html-button-or-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this.

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(){
  $(this).next().get(0).click();
})
```

Clicking on the `submit` , `trigger` an `click` for the next element which is `hyper link` in this case.

As you have a class on the href you could do this too.

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(){
  $('.ddownload-button').get(0).click();
})
```

```js
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function() {
  $(this).next().get(0).click();
})

$('a').on('click', function() {
  alert('Ram clicked')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" value="Try a sample" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit">
<a href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/pdf/AttackonNantucket.pdf" class="ddownload-button" download>Ram</a>
```

Comment: But the file is not downloading

Comment: @VijayKumarB Is file being downloading is you click directly href?

Comment: any idea about that

Comment: Looking into it

Comment: @VijayKumarB found the problem and fixed.

Comment: Thanyou very mush

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135049/discussion-between-vijay-kumar-b-and-parvez).