# Download a file in Angular/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to find a way to download a file using a location/link.
`window.open(location)` opens another tab so I'm not keen on using that.

I know there's already a `<a href='location' download>Download</a>` implementation but it does not seem to be doable right now since I'm using a custom component so I'm looking for an option like that in JavaScript.
Is there a way?

```
<custom-option (buttonClickEmitter)="downloadList(location)" [label]="translations.download"></custom-option>
```

File type is only CSV.

Thank you!

Comment: Share your code here , create a https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trigger a file download when clicking an HTML button or JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620698/how-to-trigger-a-file-download-when-clicking-an-html-button-or-javascript)

Comment: Because it is limited to use only the `<custom-option>` under `<custom-options>` so `<a><custom-option>` would be out of scope. The form tag is not really a solution

Answer (score 0):

Try **FileSaver** js library

it helps you to save any files directly from a HTTP response

https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

FileSaver saveAs(Blob/File/Url, optional DOMString filename, optional Object { autoBom })
```