# How can I use location.href to download a dmg file

Tags: javascript, html, css, dmg

So I have an issue where I have a button on my page that has a link to a dmg file however when you press the button it opens the dmg in the browser instead of downloading it.

I have tried using the download attribute but with no success.

My code:

```
<button id="DownloadByOS" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block mt-3" onclick="location.href=somerandom.dmg">Download</button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trigger a file download when clicking an HTML button or JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620698/how-to-trigger-a-file-download-when-clicking-an-html-button-or-javascript)

Comment: I'm afraid not I'm gunna have to remake the question as it got immediately closed

Answer (score 0):

The value you want to assign to `location.href` is a string, but `somerandom.dmg` has not be wrapped in quotation marks.

```
<button id="DownloadByOS" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block mt-3" onclick=" location.href='somerandom.dmg' ">Download</button>
```

Comment: Probably should have mentioned that it's a java script variable sorry