# Unable to download the file using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i want to download the file. I could see the file link but when i click on the link the file getting downloaded but couldn't able to open the downloaded file. I couldn't able to figure where i'm going wrong. I'm getting in this way while opening the file.
[image: i'm getting]

[image: downloaded]

Here is the code:

```
 <div>
        <b>File</b> :{" "}
        <a href="#" onClick={this.FileDownload}>
          {this.state.file}
        </a>
      </div>
```

Here is the sample code:
"https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-stallman-wbwvf"

Can anyone help me in this query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trigger a file download when clicking an HTML button or JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620698/how-to-trigger-a-file-download-when-clicking-an-html-button-or-javascript)

Comment: @DrewReese - I could download the file but i couldn't able to open the file. I want every file extension could open like .pdf, .docx., etc. I've gone through this link "https://medium.com/yellowcode/download-api-files-with-react-fetch-393e4dae0d9e" but i didnt implemented any helper.js. i just gave only file component

Comment: So is the issue then you don't know where the file was downloaded to?

Comment: @DrewReese - I 've updated my query with a snapshot. When i see in downloaded page then i'm getting blob: http://. Does blob making file crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
fetch("/api/FormDetails/" + this.props.match.params.id).then(async (response: any) => {
            const b = await response.blob();
            let a = document.createElement('a');
            let url = URL.createObjectURL(b);
            a.href = url;
            a.download = `mypdf.pdf`;
            a.click();
        }).catch(err=>showError(err))
    }
```

Your code seems fine, Please check if file extensions are correct while saving, as that might be one reason you are unable to open after download.

Comment: It is getting open in backend but through ui i couldn't able to open the file. Is there any other method for downloading the file? Please help me in this.

Comment: Through ui, you mean browser ? What is file extension ? Codesandbox doesnt show any file name, therefore file extension is not clear yet. Please check if you are able to download using CURL.

Comment: No idea, i'm new to react, Do we need to give file extensions while downloading. If yes, then how to give the extensions in file component?

Comment: You just give it appropriate filename including extension.I see you are downloading pdf.

Comment: I have added a snippet. Please see if that helps.

Comment: I'm getting same error for pdf file but when i give .docx file, it is getting open - but not showing any data in word file

Comment: .docx is just another compressed file like .zip . And thats why it is opening. I am wondering if [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) or curl are able to download correct file. Try downloading file using wget and you can identify whether issue is in javascript code or backend.

Comment: how to use wget or curl - are thery're dependencies?

Comment: They are operating system tools. Google on how to install them for your operating system. You can even try to open full file path in browser and browser will start downloading.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple method, but you have to go your URL through this=> [herokuapp.com](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/)

And this will perfectly bypass the CORS issue :) #Happy#Coding

```
fetch("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"+url)
.then(res => {
  const newBlob = await response.blob();
  const blob = new Blob([newBlob], {type:'application/pdf'})
}).catch(error => console.log(error)
```