# How to create a download button in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a button that triggers a download of a JSON file. (And please i don't want to use any libraries to achieve this). Thank you.

```
import Data from '../Data';

let data = Data;

<Button>Download</Button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trigger a file download when clicking an HTML button or JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620698/how-to-trigger-a-file-download-when-clicking-an-html-button-or-javascript)

Comment: Is the JSON static data? Why not just put the JSON file on the server and just provide a link for the user to click?

Comment: @EmileBergeron how would i do that. Can you provide a sample code?

Comment: It really depends on your project setup. You should include an [mcve] and more information on the data, how the project is hosted, etc. Are you using Create-React-App? Next.js? Gatsby? React manually?

Answer (score 1):

Triggering browser download from front-end is not reliable.

What you should do is, create an endpoint that when called, will provide the correct response headers, thus triggering the browser download.

Front-end code can only do so much. The 'download' attribute for example, might just open the file in a new tab depending on the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this solution: [How to create a file in memory for user to download, but not through server?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18197341/2430549)  I have rewritten their code a bit, but basically for your case, you'd want...

```
    // Set globals
var mimetype = 'application/json';
var filename = 'yourfile.json';

    // Create Dummy A Element
var a = window.document.createElement('a');

    // createObjectURL for local data as a Blob type
a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], {
    encoding: "UTF-8",
    type: mimetype + ";charset=UTF-8",
}));
a.download = filename;

    // Download file and remove dummy element
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
a.remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a file using your data and then create a downloadable link 
and append it in whichever part of your application you would like to.

```
 const fileName = "file";
 const json = JSON.stringify(data);
 const blob = new Blob([json],{type:'application/json'});
 const href = await URL.createObjectURL(blob); // Create a downloadable link
 const link = document.createElement('a');       
 link.href = href;
 link.download = fileName + ".json";
 document.body.appendChild(link);   // This can any part of your website
 link.click();
 document.body.removeChild(link);
```