# Save a DOM item to a list?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, react-redux

I have to design a CRUD but the next thing is to create a figure of grids and that when you click on a grid it is painted and give it a name and save it

[image]

And after that list them, that as they are added to put the last and so on

[image]

I should do this using React and if possible implement it with redux.

What makes me stupid is that I don't know how to save an html element locally as a photo or something like that, I'm new to React and I don't know how to implement it

Comment: [This should help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620698/how-to-trigger-a-file-download-when-clicking-an-html-button-or-javascript)

Comment: You should keep questions specific and focused. You should try it first and then come back with a specific issue you faced.

Comment: I will try it and I will return