# How to make a button using html that will cause a zip file to be downloaded

Tags: html, web

On my website I have a downloads page and I want to know how to make a button that will cause the user to download a zip file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trigger a file download when clicking an HTML button or JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620698/how-to-trigger-a-file-download-when-clicking-an-html-button-or-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have button instead of link, you can it like this:

```
<button onclick="loadFile()">Download</button>
```

and JavaScript:

```
function loadFile() {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = "./fileToDownload.zip";
    a.download = "true";
    document.body.append(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

If you consider using link, you can do it much easier:

```
<a href="./fileToDownload.zip" download >Download</a>
```

Comment: @BlackHatGorilla if you found my answer helpful, please mark it as accepted. You can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer