# Converting blob file to its file type correctly when downloading in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement file upload/download in my website.

When I'm doing the download part, I send `Content-Type: 'application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8'` as a part of the request's headers.

When I get it, I can see the blob file in the Networks tab of my dev tools. When I see the response of what is supposed to be a `.png` file, I can see some stuff related to png, or an image file, and when it's supposed to be an `.xlsx` file (my primary objective to get it working), I can see stuff related to xml so I'm pretty sure the blob is correct. However, when I download it as such:

```js
//when the GET request sends a successful response
blob = new Blob([dataDownload.value]);

//when the download button is clicked (only visible if blob is present)
if (blob) {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.download = `my-file-name.xlsx`;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    console.log('download complete');
}
```

I can't open the file. Same with if I upload and try to download a `.png` file and change the file extensions either in code or manually by overwriting the file extension.

When the same request is tested locally on insomnia/postman, it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a security hazard if a website could automatically download a file onto your computer? I'm guessing you are running into a security measure related to that, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Codebling it does not automatically download the file, only when the user presses the button (the file name, in a list) if it exists.

Comment: But you create an anchor pointing to the blob and click it - what is that doing?

Comment: @Codebling that block of code is executed when the user clicks on the file name, so it's downloading. I referred to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70329045/how-do-i-programmatically-download-a-file-using-the-browsers-native-download-wi) and other similar threads to implement that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out. I admittedly don't know much about the browser security on this front but I do seem to recall some popups when sites were trying to download files directly - now I'm curious to know the actual rules around that.

Comment: @Codebling right, I thought there would be a bit more elegant way to handle downloading files, but I can't seem to find much on it. `msSaveOrOpenBlob` seems to have deprecated too.

Comment: what does `I can't open the file.` mean? the one you downloaded? why can't you open it? it's not the browsers fault if you can't open a file on your computer

Comment: @JaromandaX By "I cannot open the file", I mean that when I upload an `.xlsx` file and download it by naming it `....xlsx`, I expect it to open without a problem. I see this behaviour when I try it on insomnia, but I do not when I download it via frontend. Hence, I expect something is wrong with my code, which I have included in my question. If my computer for some reason cannot open `.xlsx` files in general, I would notice that.

Comment: how big is the file you've downloaded? do you see any errors in teh browser developer tools?

Comment: @JaromandaX all the files I've tried so far, all less than 50KB. I do not see any errors in console or the network tab. I can see the blob in the Preview panel in the network tab and it seems to be the correct blob, albeit I cannot read much of it.

Comment: so, what is the content of the file you downloaded? surely you can open it in something to find out

Comment: @JaromandaX Most of it is just unreadable data [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SvDL.png).

Comment: so, it's a PNG - with what looks like some XML in it (that seems to be exif info though so that's fine) - so, this is what you get when you try to download am xlsx file?

Comment: @JaromandaX as I've also explained in my question, I have tried with `.png` and `.xlsx` files. This is what I get when I try to download a `.png` file. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDHti.png) is a part of what I get when I download an `.xlsx` file. My question is primarily that the incoming data seems to be correct, but I cannot determine if it's encoding issue or some other that prevents me from opening these files correctly.

Comment: looks like a perfectly valid PNG file