# Download pdf with annotaation

Tags: adobe-embed-api

Is there any way to download pdf with annotation (using adobe embed api) without opening pdf in viewer?

In my application I have download button , if I click on that button then its should start download pdf with annotation.

Answer (score 1):

So, annotations are part of a PDF. If it's in the PDF already, just link to it. If you want to force a download, use the download attribute:

```html
<a href="foo.pdf" download>Download my awesome PDF</a>
```

Comment: I'm so confused by your response. :) Does your PDF document have the annotations on them already? If so, they are part of the file, and as I said, you just have to let people download it.

Comment: What I am doing is, I have save annotation string in different location & original pdf in different location. Annotation and pdf is not in same file. While loading annotation viewer  I am binding the annotation & pdf. So from annotation viewer i can download pdf with annotation. Now my requirement is how do i download pdf with annotation without opening the annotation viewer.

Comment: What is the annotation viewer? If you are using PDF Embed, then you can dynamically add annotations to a PDF, and you can force a download.

Comment: i am using pdf-embed-api & my code is in angular. How do I force to download pdf ?

Comment: I showed that in the answer above. If you want to do it dynamically, you can generate an Anchor DOM element and fire the click event automatically. This is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49917066/52160