# Trigger a download file in html webpage such that it asks about where you want to download in pc

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am working on an application with HTML and javascript, I am creating a button to download a file by using the code



but by using this the file gets downloaded instantly I want it to be such that it asks where you want to download the file on your computer I am all new to coding please help.

Comment: Greetings, can you give us a minimal reproducable example for what you have tried so far?

Comment: Also, probably duplicate content. Check here if that helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620698/how-to-trigger-a-file-download-when-clicking-an-html-button-or-javascript in combination with the correct settings for [downloads.download()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/download)

Comment: <a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
  <img src="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">
</a> i have tried this